# Drupal template files view-block vs regular block

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-blocks, drupal-templates

When creating template files, when is it preferable to create a view-block template instead of a regular block template?

**To be specific:**
block--views--{view's machine_name}-block.tpl.php
**VS.**
block--myblock.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, views block templates are specific blocks generated with views. You'd never use a views block template to control a normal block. Normal block templates would be used to control the output of normal blocks (blocks generated from the `Structure > Blocks > Add block` control panel.